# How to know which row was selected from another Frame?

Tags: java, sql, database

In the first Jframe I have a JTable filled from database and i need to pass data of the selected jTable to another frame.

So I need to know from another JInternalFrame which row was selected in the First Jframe

```
public void showTableData() {
        try {
            Class.forName(driverName);
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
            String sql = "SELECT t.name, t.exam, l.coursename\n"
                    + "FROM exam AS t\n"
                    + "INNER JOIN Course as l ON (t.LendaID=l.LendaID)";
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            int i = 0;
            Jtable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage(), "Error",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
```

This is the table I've in the first Jframe

Comment: _In the first frame_ Do you mean `JFrame` ?

Comment: Yes, thats what i meant

Comment: So does your app contain two `JFrame`s ?

Answer (score 0):

Regardless the number of your components, as a simple solution, you can create a `CourseEventDispatcher` class to be central point to dispatch course events across the application.

```
public class CourseEventDispatcher {
 private List<CourseEventSubscriber> subscribers;

 // ...

 public void dispatchEvent(CourseEvent event) {
   for(CourseEventSubscriber: subscribers) {
     if( event.getSource() != subscriber ) {
        subscriber.onCourseEvent(event);
     }
   }
 }
}
```

And for each relevant view, there is a controller which is a CourseEventSubscriber:

```
public class SomeFrameController implements CourseEventSubscriber {
  private CourseEventDispatcher courseEventDispatcher;

  public SomeFrameController(CourseEventDispatcher courseEventDispather) {
    this.courseEventDispatcher = courseEventDispatcher;
  }

  public void addSelectionListener() {
    // ...
    table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(
        new ListSelectionListener() {
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
             doYourOwnStuff();
             // then dispatch the event
             courseEventDispatcher.dispatch(new CourseEvent(this, event));
            }
        }
    );
  }

  // from some other view 
  public void onCourseEvent(CourseEvent event) {
   // process the event
   // e.g. event.getEvent()
  }
}
```

And CourseEvent is a simple class of

```
public class CourseEvent {
  private CourseEventSubscriber source;
  private EventObject event;

  public CourseEvent(CourseEventSubscriber source, EventObject event) {
   this.source = source;
   this.event = event;
  }
  // getters
}
```

You can add(register) your controllers after you created a dispatcher.

Hope this gives you another perspective.